# Undefined value due to variable not being set in time

Tags: angular

I have an issue whereby a variable is not being set in time. A header is being set before the variable which dictates what header elements to show and what not to show is being instantiated. Here is my code

```
isDisabledCorporates(): boolean {
  if (this.userRole == 'HR Admin' || 'HR Recruiter' || 'HR Manager' || 'Candidate' || 'Operations administrator' || 'Internal Account Manager') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

  <button class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/corporate/dashboard']" *ngIf="isDisabledCorporates()"> Corporates </button>
```

this.userRole is stored in localstorage but is not being set in time so the function returns false before returning true

I get the userRole value from a service

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._userService.getCurrentUserProfileData()
      .subscribe((user) => {
        this.userRole = user;
      }
    );
  }
```

My question is how do I make sure that the userRole is set before placing the html so that I don't get the undefined before the actual role value exists

Comment: Are these two different userRole variables? Injecting the Service into the Component you use isDisabledCorporates with doesnt work?

Comment: OK. But... what is your question?

Comment: @RaphaelMayer sorry updated it

Comment: Use *ngIf: `<the-element-you-want-to-display-when-role-is-known *ngIf="userRole">...</the-element-you-want-to-display-when-role-is-known>`

Comment: The cause seems to be something else. I have hard coded the role and it still shows the corporate button :/

Comment: It's hard to understand what the problem is if you don't tell it clearly. Note that your code is incorrect though. Instead of `if (this.userRole == 'HR Admin' || 'HR Recruiter' || ...)`, the code should be `if (this.userRole == 'HR Admin' || this.userRole == 'HR Recruiter' || this.userRole == ...)`

Comment: @skydev does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your if statement is wrong. You need to check every statement:

```
isDisabledCorporates(): boolean {
    if (
      this.userRole == 'HR Admin' || 
      this.userRole == 'HR Recruiter' || 
      this.userRole == 'HR Manager' || 
      this.userRole == 'Candidate' || 
      this.userRole == 'Operations administrator' || 
      this.userRole =='Internal Account Manager') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I've created a small working sample on stackblitz, have a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8cvor
You can change the return value of the observable provided by the service to see the change in result.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you need you ngIf to be bind to property not method, and this property should be changed with the subscriber to userData

Answer (score -2):

Seems a basic issue of async operations. Basically you should never try to bind the value from a function call to the view. You should always use variables to bind the value.

Instead of calling the function from view you can have a flag variable that initially set to some value say `false`. When you get the response from `getCurrentUserProfileData()` function you can again set the flag back.

This may work.

```typescript
corporatesDisabled = false;

ngOnInit() {
  this._userService.getCurrentUserProfileData()
    .subscribe((user) => {
      this.userRole = user;
      this.corporatesDisabled = this.isDisabledCorporates();
    }
  );
}

isDisabledCorporates(): boolean {
  if (this.userRole == 'HR Admin' || 'HR Recruiter' || 'HR Manager' || 'Candidate' || 'Operations administrator' || 'Internal Account Manager') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/corporate/dashboard']" *ngIf="corporatesDisabled"> Corporates </button>
```

Comment: That won't change anything, except the change detection will be a tiny bit faster.